# New blocks delay in my full node

Tags: bsc, full-node

I am subscribed to the new blocks on my node:

> newHeads Fires a notification each time a new header is appended to
> the chain, including chain reorganizations

I have a node that exceeds two on the recommended hardware. The ram is always at 50% and the CPU at 25%, and network at 10%.

In the connection parameters, I have indicated that it connects to 1000 nodes (I have been testing values ​​between 30 and 1000)

I am measuring the latency from when a new block is created, until that block reaches me. The problem is that sometimes there is a very high latency, I have seen peaks of up to 20 seconds, is it normal?

```
New block:  11706845 546 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706846 2454 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706847 529 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706848 2510 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706849 1760 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706850 644 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706851 1796 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706852 1268 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706853 529 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706854 1502 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
//-- Latency start
New block:  11706855 1273 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706856 17785 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706857 15094 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706858 12786 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706859 10041 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706860 7287 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706861 4596 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706862 1961 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706863 1322 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706864 1231 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
//--
New block:  11706865 817 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706866 410 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706867 2362 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706868 413 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706869 429 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706870 1646 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706871 923 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706872 574 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706873 1561 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706874 1377 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
New block:  11706875 607 ms  blocksTimeDelta: 3000
```